# Есть такая фунция на Javascript, как изменить ее, чтобы она выбирала не все элементы тега <form>, а лишь отдельные?

Tags: javascript, php, html

```js
function checkboxes_sel_all(obj)
  {
  // Получаем NodeList дочерних элементов input формы:
  var items = obj.form.getElementsByTagName("input"), len, i;
 
  for (i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i += 1)
    {
    // Если текущий элемент является чекбоксом
    if (items.item(i).type && items.item(i).type === "checkbox")
      {
      if (obj.checked)
        {
        // Устанавливаем отметки всем чекбоксам
        items.item(i).checked = true;
        }
      else
        {
        // Иначе снимаем отметки со всех чекбоксов:
        items.item(i).checked = false;
        }      
      }
    }
  }
```

```html
  <form method='post'>
  <div><input type='checkbox' name="set" onclick="checkboxes_sel_all(this)"></div>
  <table>
  ...
  <td><input type='checkbox'  name='words[]' value='$eng, $ru '>$eng, $ru </td>
  <td><input type='checkbox'  name='words[]' value='$eng, $ru '>$eng, $ru </td>
  ...
  </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: А как эта функция поймет, какие элементы вы считаете `отдельными`?

Comment: В jquery есть, а так можно вручную if, можно вручную лямбдами.

Answer (score 1):

Корректней было бы присвоить классы необходимым элементам, и в функции обращаться уже к ним:

```
function checkboxes_sel_all(obj)
  {
  // Получаем NodeList дочерних элементов input формы:
  var items = obj.form.getElementsByClassName("test"), len, i;

  for (i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i += 1)
    {
    // Если текущий элемент является чекбоксом
    if (items.item(i).type && items.item(i).type === "checkbox")
      {
      if (obj.checked)
        {
        // Устанавливаем отметки всем чекбоксам
        items.item(i).checked = true;
        }
      else
        {
        // Иначе снимаем отметки со всех чекбоксов:
        items.item(i).checked = false;
        }      
      }
    }
  }
```

```
  <form method='post'>
  <div><input type='checkbox' name="set" onclick="checkboxes_sel_all(this)"></div>
  <table>
  ...
  <td><input class ='test' type='checkbox'  name='words[]' value='$eng, $ru '>$eng, $ru </td>
  <td><input type='checkbox'  name='words[]' value='$eng, $ru '>$eng, $ru </td>
  ...
  </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: пример бы, вероятно, не помешал. [edit]